# Gorm dynamic finder vs Grails injected property type

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes as follows:

```
class Field {

    static hasMany = [options: Option]

}

class Option {

  String caption

  static belongsTo = [field: Field]
  static mappedBy = [field: Field]

   static constraints = {
    caption maxSize: 255
   }
}
```

My question is: When do I use field.options and when do I use Options.findAllByField()? My unit tests which were using field.options (grails injected property types) are now starting to fail after switching to HibernateTestMixin (which uses an in memory database). They will only pass if I switch to the Gorm dynamic finders. What am I doing wrong? :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, that is wrong is the usage of mappedBy. You should use this for associations, if you have multiple properties of the same type. I suggest to remove the part:

```
static mappedBy = [field: Field]
```

But this will most probably not solve your issue.

If you have an field instance (attached to the hibernate session), then you should use the natural:

```
Set options = field.options
```

When your field instance gets detached from hibernate session and its options association is not loaded (because of lazy-loading), then issuing `field.options` will throw LazyInitializationException.

Please post the error you get, when using field.options in your tests. Maybe your field instance got detached from the session (which could be caused by RuntimeException thrown from a transactional service).